# Linking two brothers via gravestones

Tags: jewish, ukraine, burial-records, holocaust

I am doing research about my great-grandfather who was Jewish and had a brother who survived the Holocaust in Ukraine. I've found a gravestone image via a website which documents Jewish genealogy which looks like it could be the brother of my great-grandfather. The person whose gravestone I've found has the same family name as my great-grandfather, the same father name and also the same year of death. I know the year of death from my grandfather. I just don't know the first name of his brother and my grandfather doesn't remember it. How can I make certain that it was him? I'm almost 90% sure it's him since the Jewish community in that place was almost annihilated and I don't think there can be two person whose data can coincide this much.

Family name for both is Oks. Father's name of my great-grandfather is Boruch. Father name of my great-grandfather's supposed brother (on gravestone) is Shlomeh-Barukh. I didn't attach the image because it is in Russian. I wonder if at the cemetery they keep additional details, like mother's name - that would confirm the link.

Comment: I would suggest to link the image and provide genealogical notes on both individuals to help us to come to a decision.

Comment: Family name for both is Oks. Father's name of my great-grandfather is Boruch. Father name of my great-grandfather's supposed brother (on gravestone) is Shlomeh-Barukh. I didn't attache the image since anyway it's in Russian. I wonder if at the cemetery they keep additional details, like mother's name - that would confirm the link.

Comment: Have you considered posting a query to the appropriate mailing list at Jewishgen.org or Rootsweb.org?  Following up on cemetery records is a good idea -- that may contain other information that will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Whether in English or in Russian, almost all Jewish gravestones for males also give the Hebrew name of the person followed by the Hebrew word "ben" meaning "son of" followed by the Hebrew name of their father. This may have a suffix of "hacohen" or "halevi" in Hebrew if they are from the male line of the Priests or the Levites.

You say in your comment that your great-grandfather's name is Boruch. Was this from other information, or was it specifically from his gravestone? Do you have his gravestone image? If so, compare the Hebrew name on the gravestone image to his supposed brother's image, which you say reads Shlomeh-Barukh.

The Boruch / Barukh should both look similar to this:  [image]

If both have "halevi" or both have "hacohen" or both have no suffix, then that makes it more likely, but if only one has a suffix or they are different, then that makes it very unlikely.

Comment: I took a look at your website. Pretty interesting, especially considering my interest in genealogy and the fact that your ancestors are from Moldova (Moldavia, Bessarabia), where I'm originally from (and some of my ancestors). It's a small world, isn't it? :-)

Comment: One more thing. If you need some help with records, photos, etc., containing text in Russian and/or Romanian, I might be able to help, at least, I can try.

Comment: Thanks @AleksandrBlekh for the offer of help. If you've got some Jewish connections, then maybe we'll find some common relatives.

Comment: You're very welcome. And, yes, I do, so that might be interesting. Please feel free to connect.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the location, there might exist municipal or, more likely, church records of the location's residents. I would suggest trying to contact local municipal and/or church authorities, which might have these records in possession. Another route is to find a local person who could find/retrieve/request this information for you. Also, as far as I know, some lawyers provide such services, usually for a fee. By the way, may I ask what area (city/town/villiage) of Ukraine are you talking about?